# Spring Reactive WebClient with merge unit tests do not terminate

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am experimenting with Reactive Spring and WebClient and particularly trying to call different clients simultaneously and merge the results in the end. Maybe it is important to share beforehand, that it could be expected that one of services does not always return a value.

So I have this simple service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class PersonSearchService {

    public static final String PERSON_SERVICE = "/persons";
    public static final String FELLOW_SERVICE = "/fellows";

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public PersonSearchService(@Value("${base.url}") String baseUrl) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();
    }
    
    // This method is called from a controller where a SearchCriteria is being passed - Not important
    public Flux<PersonResult> getPeople(SearchCriteria search) {
        return Flux.merge(
            getPeople(PERSON_SERVICE, search),
            getPeople(FELLOW_SERVICE, search));
    }

    private Flux<PersonResult> getPeople(String path, SearchCriteria search) {
        
        return webClient.get()
            .uri(path, search)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, ErrorHandler::handleError)
            .bodyToFlux(PersonResult.class);
    }
}
```

And both of the above services return the same result:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class PersonResult {
    private String personId;
    private int age;
    
    //getters + setters + constructor omitted for clarity
}
```

So this works as expected, but when I try to unit test it, my tests never terminate (the connection stays active). Here is my test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PersonSearchServiceTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;
    private PersonSearchServiceTest personSearchService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        personSearchService = new PersonSearchServiceTest(mockWebServer.url("localhost").toString());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    void getPeople_empty() {
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .setBody("[]"));

        SearchCriteria search = SearchCriteria.builder().build();

        Flux<PersonResult> resultFlux = personSearchService.getPeople(search);

        StepVerifier.create(resultFlux)
            .expectNextCount(0)
            .verifyComplete();

//
//        assertThat(this.personSearchService.getPeople(search).collectList().block())
//            .isEqualTo(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    @Test
    void getDataPlanParcels() throws Exception {
        var person = PersonResult.builder()
            .id("1234")
            .age(20)
            .build();

        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person)));

        SearchCriteria search = Search.builder().build();
        Flux<PersonResult> resultFlux = personSearchService.getPeople(search);

        StepVerifier.create(resultFlux)
            .expectNextMatches(result -> result.getId().equals("1234"))
            .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

Any of the two tests above does not terminate and waits and this is what I see in my terminal:

```
00:07:09.209 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations.debug(244) - [id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281] Received last HTTP packet <no request,no span> 
00:07:09.218 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.debug(249) - [id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281] onStateChange(GET{uri=/localhost/license-service/v3/ACPMDE/parcels/search, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281]}}, [response_completed]) <no request,no span> 
00:07:09.220 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.debug(249) - [id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281] onStateChange(GET{uri=/localhost/license-service/v3/ACPMDE/parcels/search, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281]}}, [disconnecting]) <no request,no span> 
00:07:09.220 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.debug(244) - [id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281] Releasing channel <no request,no span> 
00:07:09.224 [reactor-http-epoll-3] DEBUG r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.debug(249) - [id: 0xee38099d, L:/127.0.0.1:49742 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:43281] Channel cleaned, now 1 active connections and 1 inactive connections <no request,no span>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the testing setup? Or do I need to extra configuration on the WewbClient?
If I remove the `Flux.merge` or there is only one source, then the tests are green.

Comment: it looks to me you are only setting up one response from your mock server. So first call goes well, then the second is made and server is waiting for a response from the mockserver. So if you wait long enough it might timeout. So maybe `enqueue` two responses.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to test what happens exactly when only one response comes. I.e. that could also happen in "real" life - only one of these services could provide a response based on the `search` and the other one has no matches.

Comment: ideally, if a `search` call has no matches, you would still receive a response denoting that the `search` api found no responses for the search criteria passed in.

Comment: if you would like to simulate no response at all then you should be setting a read timeout on your web client and providing a suitable `onError` operator to handle that failure.

Comment: Yeah, both of the services provide a response even if nothing is being found. I played around with Wiremock server instead of okhttp Mock Web Server and I am not having the same issues. So it must be related to my test setup, but I don't want to be explicitly doing `enqueue`  for every service.